# I cannot complete the "Storybook for Angular" tutorial

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm just recently learning about Storybook and see how it's going to help in UI design and development... So I thought to start with [its Angular tutorial](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/get-started/), but I got stuck in it after running the following commands on my fresh Angular workspace:

```
# Clone the template
npx degit chromaui/intro-storybook-angular-template taskbox

cd taskbox

# Install dependencies
npm install
```

Now when I run `ng run taskbox:storybook` while I'm in the 'taskbox' directory, I get `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'is-gzip'` error.  What shall I do to fix this?

I also obviously get `Project "taskbox" does not exist.` error, if I run the command while I'm at the root of my Angular project.

Anyway, I don't also see the 'is-gzip' dependency listed in the `myAngularProj/taskbox/package.json` file! I don't guess I have to change the 'package.josn' file, because I have cloned it by running the `degit` command, just how tutorial suggested!

I appreciate any help in advance. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can check on https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6984 for solution

Comment: The tutorial is meant to be a dedicated project. Based on the path of your package.json file (myAngularProj/taskbox/package.json), taskbox is living in side a parent angular project.

Comment: @Kinjal There are some similar issues... But I couldn't find my solution in that issue! Can you be more specific on how I can fix this. Is it something that I'm missing in this official tutorial here? Thx.